# Test named route in Rails 3.1 using test:unit

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, testing, routes

assuming I have a named route like this

```
match '/home' => 'site#home', :as => :home
```

how do I write a test to check the named route? i.e. if I do this

```
assert_routing '/site/home', { :controller => "site", :action => "home" }
```

the test fails becasue it is trying to match "/home" against "/site/home"

Comment: Are you sure you don't want the assert to look like this: `assert_routing '/home', {:controller => "site", :action => "home"}`? Also, do you also have a route for `'/site'`?